# axis.title = is not working in sjp.lmer() in the sjPlot package

Tags: r, axis-labels, lme4, sjplot

I'm doing some plotting of some mixed models I've been running and am pulling my hair out trying to make `sjp.lmer()` change the x and y axis labels of a fixed effect. If I'm missing something simple, please let me know!

This is my code:

```
library(sjPlot);library(lme4)

model = lmer(DV ~ IV + (1|groupingVariable), data = data, REML = F)

sjp.lmer(model, 
     type = "fe.slope", 
     vars = c("IV"),
     title = "Estimated effect of IV1 on DV", 
     geom.colors = c("black", "grey49"), 
     show.ci = T, 
     axis.title = c("IV Title", "DV Title"))
```

Model is a formal model estimated using glmer(). The problem is that regardless of what I write, the x and y labels do not change.

I think the syntax is correct, because this code works:

```
sjp.lmer(model, 
     type = "re", 
     sort.est = "sort.all", 
     facet.grid = F,
     axis.title = c("IV Title", "DV Title"))
```

This second being a plot of the random effects for the same model. Is this a bug? Can you for some reason not specify axis labels for fixed effect models? Thank you!

Seems like a bug. I've raised the issue on gitHub at:

https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/issues/212

Comment: which package is this in?

Comment: Sorry -- sjplot

Comment: You should probably mention that you've already (cross)posted this as an issue at https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/issues/212

Comment: Yeah, no one had responded, and I thought it had gone dead... but done. Thanks for the hack. Works perfectly.

Comment: Your issue requires some more work, so I did not response immediately - however, your issue is recognized. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's just an oversight ("misfeature"/bug). Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/blob/f2f398456c722e9e9803818b09312fb734c0a490/R/sjPlotLinreg.R#L690):

```
reglinplot <- reglinplot +
  labs(title = title,
       x = sjmisc::get_label(model_data[[p_v]], def.value = p_v),
       y = response)
```

it  seems the labels are hard-coded. Furthermore, the argument list of `sjp.reglin` ([here](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel/blob/f2f398456c722e9e9803818b09312fb734c0a490/R/sjPlotLinreg.R#L581)) doesn't have an `axis.title` argument ... posting an issue, as you have done, seems like the right way forward.

However, it's not too hard to hack the plot a little bit if you know just a tiny bit about the `ggplot2` package.

Set up example:

```
library(sjPlot); library(lme4
mod <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(Days|Subject),sleepstudy)
p1 <- sjp.lmer(mod, 
     type = "fe.slope", 
     vars = "Days")  ## stripped-down (warning about colour palette)
```

Hack labels:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1$plot.list[[1]] + labs(x="hello",y="goodbye")
```

Comment: axis-titles are not set for this plot-type, because you can have multiple plots (see `plot.list` return value), which all have different x-axis-titles (the name for the IV, for instance), while the y-axis is always the same title (the DV). That's why I did not implement any option for setting axis titles, and indeed the workaround is to use your suggestion to hack the labels.

Comment: Perhaps the issue becomes a documentation request then ... ?

Comment: That would be the easiest solution, and probably even easier for the user than dealing with a complicated list of values as `axis.title`-argument. I'll think this over...